# Facebook App Invite - Retrive Facebook ID of recipient

Tags: android, ios, facebook

In my app if person A invites B using app invite (As per latest app invite https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites) and when B joins app using Facebook login certain action is needed to take. As per latest app invite I could not see if I can get Facebook id of recipient. In old app invite (using FBDialog) it was there in response. My target is if I get emailid or facebook id of friends invited using Facebook App Invite then I can keep track of rest from logic in app.

Can any one please suggest if is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Use this [Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user) to access details , u can get Profile id easily using Graph API of facebook. before that you can get the access tokens after login you can get the Profile id.